# Strange 5 second pause with PHP command line interface (related to mysql/mysqli extension)

Tags: php, windows, command-line

I'm getting a strange 5 to 7 second pause when executing PHP scripts from the command-line PHP client (PHP 5.2 on Windows).

During this pause the PHP script just appears to 'freeze' for a while before returning to the command prompt.  It is not using any significant CPU time, it's like it is waiting for some delay.

After experimenting with PHP.ini, I've narrowed this down to the fact that the mysql or mysqli extension is enabled.  If these extensions are both disabled, no annoying pause and the PHP script terminates in mere milliseconds.

The command I'm using is:

```
"C:\Program Files\PHP\php.exe" -f %1
```

Where %1 is the PHP script.

The pause still occurs even if the PHP script being executed is essentially empty:

```
<?php

?>
```

Do you know what is causing this pause and how I can remove it while still allowing mysql or mysqli support for PHP on the command line?

Comment: Are you using any MySQL database functions in your code? Do you use any persistent connections? If you turn those off does it go away?

Comment: It occurs even when using no functions at all in my code.

Comment: It was just a guess. The other posters have already identified the culprit!

Comment: Problem appears fixed in current PHP 5.3 on Windows.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this thread, it solved my problem that was annoying me for many weeks!
We encountered this problem on a Win2008 server with IIS and PHP. The lucky thing is, that we do not need mysql anyhow, so we just disabled this extension.
Best regards, Jens

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it's a [bug in mysql](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=37226). you can solve it by getting the latest libmysql.dll (5.1.31 or higher. some older versions also work - see second link). make sure that's the libmysql.dll actually used and there are no other libmysql.dlls in your path. see the related [php issue](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=41350) for details.

Comment: Thankyou. Upgrading libmysql.dll in my PHP directory almost completely removed the delay. Interestingly, there is still a bit of a delay (few hundred milliseconds) compared to disabling mysql support. But the annoyance factor is solved.

Answer (score 4):

For me (Zend Server CE on Mac OS X), the imap exetension was the culprit. Disabling it solved the problem.

Anoyone wants to write a PHP extension bisecting script? :)

Comment: Thanks! this fixed it on my end using MAMP on Mac OS X Mavericks, just disabled the extension removing the line saying "extension=imap.so" in the php-cli configuration file located: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/conf/php.ini

Comment: Same here! Funny how this is an issue two years later, but disabling imap.so solved the cli delay for me as well. (MAMP PRO 3.0/OSX Yosemite)

Answer (score 3):

I also experienced an annoying 2 second delay running PHP from the command line under Windows 7 64bit.

This version had a delay:
<strike>**php.exe (v5.3.5) shipped with [ZendServer Community Edition](http://www.zend.com/en/products/server-ce/)**</strike>

This version was wonderfully quick:
**php.exe (v5.3.6) shipped with [EasyPHP](http://www.easyphp.org/)**

(Sorry to bump an ancient thread, but hopefully this helps others Googling this issue.)

Answer (score 0):

On linux in 2020 with PHP 7.4 this still happens. The solution was to link my hostname to 127.0.0.1 in the `/etc/hosts` file, so the 5 second delay was from looking up my own hostname (and not finding it). While on servers I have set up the hostnames, I didn't really do that on my desktop systems (and it does not do that automatically).

To solve it, run `hostname` on the command line (to see the hostname of the current machine) and then add this line to `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1 yourhostname
```

Where you would replace yourhostname with what `hostname` showed you.