# slow php command line performance - is this normal or do I have an install problem?

Tags: php

I have a simple PHP app that prints 'hello world'.  When I run it from the command line it takes 6 seconds.  Is this normal?  It seems to take 1 seconds before "hello world" prints, then 5 seconds after.

I am running PHP version 5.2.12 on Windows Server 2008 R2.  Could this be an install issue, or is it typical?  I did a manual install of PHP then added whatever components were needed to run Drupal.  The only PHP addon I remember adding was MDB2, CGI support is there too.

I am used to a Lua project I run from the command line, hundreds of lines of code that will run in under a second.

I have some unit tests I run from the command line, and already with just a few they are very slow.  I run them from Netbeans and the tests are still very slow.

I run precisely this:

```
C:\temp>copy con test.php
<?php
print('hello, world');
^Z
        1 file(s) copied.

C:\temp>test.php
hello, world
```

Comment: No, it is not normal. And it is not overhead of the interpreter.
What exactly you type to run it from the command line?

Comment: Maybe this is normal for PHP on Windows?

Comment: No, it is not normal. But usually we call an interpreter to run a php file, like `c:\php\php.exe c:\temp\test.php`

Comment: I just had this today. It seems to be answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/641550/strange-5-second-pause-with-php-command-line-interface-related-to-mysql-mysqli-e by saying it depends on your MySQL client library.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only way I could figure to solve this was to go through my php.ini file and look for anything weird.  Eventually I tried disabling loaded DLLs, and that address the problem.  The DLL's impacting performance were php_curl.dll and php_mysql.dll, though I only needed to remove php_curl.dll to address the problem.

php_mysql.dll doesn't cause any problems on its own.  php_curl.dll adds a 1 second delay, and a 4 second delay if used with php_mysql.dll.  I don't remember why I added php_curl.dll so I guess I'll take it out for now.

Comment: Did it do that only on the command line interface, or also when run through IIS?

Comment: I think it also happened while running under IIS but I am not certain.

Comment: I was getting a 30 second delay that was extremely frustrating. I disabled php_curl.dll and the problem vanished.