# PHP-style insert contents of file in HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a table of contents which is common to many html files that I generate. I would like all these to refer to a common table, so that if I change the table, all files reflect it and there is no need to touch them.

Is there a client-side equivalent of some PHP code like this?

```
<?php readfile("file.html"); ?>
```

I've never used PHP, but I would like to avoid the need to install server side programs to view the HTML files locally.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure your server has no PHP already? Another server option is SSI (server side includes). If you really need to do it client side, search about ajax

Comment: are all the files stored locally?

Comment: There is many client side alternetives... Any MVC framework, angular, react, `<template>` tag

Comment: I suppose you could use JavaScript for the same functionality

Comment: If you are just doing it locally, ie with `file:///` then you cannot do this without disabling the browser's web security features

Comment: @chop62: yes all local, that's the problem.

Comment: @Endless any details? thanks

Comment: @och: but how? see my comment to blex's answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use JavaScript to dynamically load HTML content.

Here is an example:

**table_of_contents.html**

```
<ul>
    <li>Section I<li>
    <li>Section II<li>
    <li>Section III<li>
</ul>
```

**Other pages you want to include the table of contents in**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Some page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="table-of-contents"></div>

    <p>Some content on your page</p>

    <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        // Create a XMLHttpRequest
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        // When it loads, insert the HTML into the container
        xhr.onload = function () {
            document.getElementById('table-of-contents').innerHTML = this.response;
        };

        // Set the request parameters
        xhr.open('GET', 'table_of_contents.html', true);
        // Send the request
        xhr.send();
    }, false);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Or, if you're using jQuery, you can do a one-liner with [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) :

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
    $('#table-of-contents').load('table_of_contents.html');
});
</script>
```

> Note that this method may only work on a server (using `http://`, not `file:\\\`), because of the Same Origin Policy that browsers implement for everyone's safety - you don't want some random website to load files from your system.

Comment: Good answer - eliminates the need for any server side code/setup +1

Comment: Good answer - shows an example without other js dependencies

Comment: I already knew of this solution and it doesn't work, console says:
"Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource."
In a slightly different situation I used this:
document.getElementById('table-of-contents').innerHTML = "<iframe src=\"" + filePath + "\"></iframe>";
which does work. If there was a way to display the frame as if it was part of the web page then this iframe thing would be a solution.

Comment: @BanK as I said in my answer, this is due to the Same Origin Policy. You need to have these files on a server (local or remote). Not on your machine using the `file:\\\` protocol.

Comment: I've installed a PHP server and this code (<?php readfile("file.html"); ?>) works if I rename .html files into .php. But it's strange to make all the html content go through the PHP engine. There is no way to explicitly call a .php file from HTML?

Comment: @BanK It does not matter which extension you choose if your files don't include php code (otherwise, it does). In your case, you could probably have all of your files in .html format, and just the one with php code in .php format (If I guessed correctly what's in your files)

Comment: OK, but how do I that? I want to basically put <?php readfile("table-of-contents.html"); ?> in all the .html files, but this is PHP code... is there a way to reference one PHP script from all the .html files?

Comment: @BanK If you follow the example in my answer, there is no need for PHP at all. I'm confused. I thought you did not want to use PHP? Why do you want to use php's readfile function, instead of loading table_of_contents.html directly?

Comment: Yes I was confused -- since I'm forced to use a server apparently, might as well do the HTTP request way. Thanks. But somehow now with a local server, everything is far slower (I use command line "php -S localhost:8000" to create a server). Any advice on this?

Comment: @BanK I'm sorry, but I'm afraid I can't help you with that :( I've not experienced any slowness using a local server (I've been using Wamp for Windows - there's also Mamp for Mac). Maybe this question is related to your problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528371/slow-php-command-line-performance-is-this-normal-or-do-i-have-an-install-probl