# PHP curl initiated with bash or file_get_contents - slow

Tags: php, performance, curl

I have a simple PHP curl script that checks my localhost for updates and etc. It works fast, if I open the .php in a browser - it loads instantly. However if I want to integrate the file using file_get_contents in another PHP file, or just testing - run it through bash - it takes like 5 seconds to finish!! The text response itself appears almost instantly, but then a cursor blinks for 3-5 seconds and only then finishes the request.

How can I make the curl script not take so long to cleanup or whatever it's doing so long?

```
$url='http://nodes:1041/?request=speed';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

$store = curl_exec($ch);
$array = json_decode($store, true);

if(!$array['nodes']) {
    echo 'Nothing running';
} else {
    foreach($array['nodes'] as $key => $speed) {
        $upload += $speed[0];
        $dnload += $speed[1];
    }
}

echo 'Down: ' . $dnload . '/s\n';
echo 'Up: ' . $upload .'/s\n';

curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: give us your code. we can't help without that.

Comment: I'll add the code, but it doesn't make a difference. Every time I use a php file with curl inside, it takes 5 seconds or so to finish, while in the browser it's instant

Comment: in the browser it just LOOKS instant, it's an huge difference. My bet is that you don't properly close the curl handlers.

Comment: Try adding a [`Connection: close`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.10) header to the request.

Comment: @DaveRandom where do I add this?

Comment: @Matt You would use the `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` option, or with `file_get_contents()` you would use a [stream context](http://php.net/manual/en/stream.contexts.php).

Comment: @STTLCU - it takes the script 0.002 seconds to finish. When viewed from a browser - that's how long it takes to see it. When initiated from a command line `php script.php`, or with `file_get_contents()` - it takes like 3-5seconds.

Comment: @DaveRandom adding that to the curl options didn't help. I'm still stuck with having to wait an additional few seconds after the curl is finished, so that I could continue on with the script..

Comment: @Matt are you testing this on Windows by any chance?

Comment: @Matt See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/641550/strange-5-second-pause-with-php-command-line-interface-related-to-mysql-mysqli - http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=37226 - https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=50410 - TL;DR update your PHP and MySQL versions.

Comment: @DaveRandom - but this delay only applies when using curl. I do not have the same issues the people in your links have, just when using curl. MySQL works fine, echoing is fine, but CURL forces the script to wait after completion.

Comment: @Matt See the extra PHP bug link I just added, it appears there were two different bugs, one with MySQL and one with libcurl, which had similar effects. What PHP version are you running?